# dynamically Binding GridView Rows using DropDownList headers as filter strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to get this to work all day. I need to filter the gridview based on what is in the dropdownlists in the headers. I can do that in my code-behind, but how do i then bind the table that I created to the gridview? gridview.databind() does not work in this situation since the columns are not databound columns.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" CellPadding="3"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        AllowSorting="True" SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc-header" 
        SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc-header"
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="17" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PagerStyle-Font-Names="WebDings" PagerStyle-Font-Size="Medium"
        PagerSettings-FirstPageText=" 7 " PagerSettings-PreviousPageText=" 3 " 
        PagerSettings-NextPageText=" 4 " PagerSettings-LastPageText=" 8 " 
          Font-Size="Small" onpageindexchanging="GridView3_PageIndexChanging" 
          onsorting="GridView3_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ondatabound="GridView3_DataBound">

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" />

             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time" DataField="Time"/>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="TypeList" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="134px" 
                    DataSourceId="dsWarningType" 
                    DataTextValue="Name" DataValueField="Name">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                 </HeaderTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Process" >
             <HeaderTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="Process" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="134px" 
                   >
                  </asp:DropDownList>
             </HeaderTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Index" >
             <HeaderTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="Index" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="134px" 
                   >
                  </asp:DropDownList>
             </HeaderTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Body" DataField="Body"/>

         </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

<PagerSettings FirstPageText=" 7 " LastPageText=" 8 " Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"      NextPageText=" 4 " PreviousPageText=" 3 "></PagerSettings>

        <PagerStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DCE2E8" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc-header"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc-header"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
      </asp:GridView>
```

When I create my table, it binds the Date, Time, and Body fields just fine, but leaves the Type,Process, and Index fields blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eval or Bind to bind the dropdownlists
example

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Process" >
         <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="Process" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="134px" 
              Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' 
              </asp:DropDownList>
         </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I get an exception when I use Eval instead of Bind:

'TypeList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

If all of them are Bind, the columns still do not populate

Comment: @user1060498 user eval only when you have to read data . You have bind  all your dropdowns with sqldatasource ?